# Insert Laravel model with multiple foreign keys

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Here's my situation: a User can Comment on a Video.  Comment belongs to both the video and the user.  My models look like this:

```php
class Comment extends Eloquent {
    public function video()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Video');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}

class User extends Eloquent {
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Comment');
    }
}

class Video extends Eloquent {
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Comment');
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to insert a comment:

```php
$comment = new Comment;
$comment->content = 'content';
Auth::user()->comments()->save($comment);
```

This throws a `Integrity constraint violation` error from SQL, because it only updates one foreign key.  Doing it the opposite way (saving to the video) produces the same result.  How do I add it to both models at once, updating both foreign keys?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem you're having right now is that you're lazy loading the `comments` of the `Auth::user`.

One thing you can do I believe, is to use the `associate` method in the Eloquent Models, please try this and see if it works for your specific needs.

```
// Get the video of the comment relation
$video = Video::find(Input::get('video_id')) ;

// Use the associate method to include
// the id of the others model
$comment = new Comment;
$comment->content = 'content';
$comment->user()->associate(Auth::user());
$comment->video()->associate($video);
$comment->save();
```

Comment: Perfect.  I wasn't aware that associate only set the ID, rather than setting and saving.  Thanks!

Comment: You should also look into polymorphic relationships, they were done exactly for the situation you described.

Comment: thank you @gpopoteur
you have no idea how many hours i spent figuring out how to save a new model that had multiple relationships. Polymorphic works if you want the new model to only work with one instance of the new model, but not if you want it to belong to many 'owners'